# UICollectionView overwriting cell label when scrolled off screen and back on

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a test app with a UICollectionView that draws its cells correctly when they first come on screen, but overlays the label text with new text that changes and is placed differently when the cell is scrolled off and back on the screen.

Here's how it looks when app opens:
[image: Original view]

Here's how it looks after scrolling off and on:

[image: after scrolling]

This is the code that dequeues the cell and adds the label:

```
func collectionViewTableLayoutManager(manager: DRCollectionViewTableLayoutManager!, collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForRow row: UInt, column: UInt, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell! {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(collectionViewCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
cell.layer.borderWidth = 1

let subViews = cell.contentView.subviews

let labels = subViews.filter {$0 is UILabel } as! [UILabel]
let label: UILabel


if let lbl = labels.first {
    label = lbl

} else {

    label = UILabel(frame: cell.bounds)
    label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)
    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.addSubview(label)
}

label.text = "\(indexPath.section):\(indexPath.row) / \(row):\(column)"

return cell

}
```

Any ideas? Is it the label.text line and the cell is getting different values for IndexPath and row and column. I though that these were kept in sync to draw the cell correctly with the right information. (This all works fine in Obj C)

Comment: I think the problem is that it always goes to 'else' case, so it just keep adding more labels to the cell, and they overlap each other

Comment: stop adding subviews in cellForRow Method . its creating subviews again and again on the Same row. Add the Label in Cell  in xib or initWithFrame: With of Cell  then retrive it via IBOutlets or viewWithTag:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the label to the cell directly, but checking for the presence of the label in the cell's `contentView`. Try adding the label to the cell's `contentView` instead and it should work.

Typically, if you know all these cells will need that label, you should create a new cell class that has its own label already in it. That way the collection view data source doesn't have to inspect the cell contents and conditionally create a label; the label will already be present waiting to accept the string.

Comment: Absolutely correct. That fixed it. I understand conceptually about the cell class and why it makes sense. I'll see if I can implement it.

Comment: Another option: In the cell's prepareForReuse, you can remove the label. It'll be happily re-created by your existing code.